# Using Lambda expressions to query DataTable filled by SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, datatable

I am building a WinForm that displays the number of appointments for each customer in a DataGridView. I can do this with a basic SELECT statement, but the requirements call for at least 2 Lambda Expressions. I have created 1 Lambda expression, but so far it doesn't do anything. From what I understand, a Lambda can be used to query a DataTable similar to how a SQL statement queries a table. But for some reason, nothing happens. The DataTable fills fine, but the Lambda doesn't do anything.

Here is the entirety of the code for the WinForm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Linq;


namespace C969_Software_2
{
public struct Customer
{
    public string customerName;
    public int numberOfApps;
}

public partial class CustomerReports : Form
{
    public CustomerReports()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customerReportView.DataSource = getReport();
    }


    public static DataTable getReport()
    {
        string SqlString = "SELECT * FROM customer";
        MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(SqlUpdater.conString);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(SqlString, c);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        c.Open();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(i => i.Field<int>("customerId") == 1)
            .Select(i => new { name = i.Field<string>("customerName")});

     return dt;
    }
}
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: The Lamba function isn't being told to do anything. It's like a canned query that doesn't execute until required. You can make it run by appending `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`.

Comment: AlwaysLearning: Thanks for the tip! Now I've seen some instances where people were able to use .CopyToDataTable(), but that doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: `.CopyToDataTable()` won't work here because it expects an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` as a source, whereas you're Selecting an `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousObject>`. i.e.: Your `.Select()` statement is returning a new object.

Comment: @PatrickDavis, also, pls add `@` symbol before usernames so they have been notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the intent of your Linq query is to get the name of customerId 1, try the following...

```cs
//This creates the query as IEnumerable<someAnonymousRuntimeObject> but doesn't execute it.
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => i.Field<int>("customerId") == 1)
    .Select(i => new { name = i.Field<string>("customerName") });

//This actually executes the query and stores the result in name
var name = query.FirstOrDefault().name;
```

=== Edit ===

It's a little vague as to what you're expecting to return from getReport().

If, as your Linq Select statement suggests, you're only wanting the `customerName` for `customerId == 1`, you can do that with:

```cs
var name = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => i.Field<int>("customerId") == 1)
    .Select(i => i.Field<string>("customerName"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
return name;
```

If you're wanting a `DataTable` containing only the row whose `customerId == 1` you can do that with:

```cs
var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => i.Field<int>("customerId") == 1)
    .CopyToDataTable();
return dt2;
```

This returns a single row with the customerId, customerName and whatever other columns are returned by your `SELECT *` statement.

Neither of the above approaches are particularly efficient, though. As your database grows and the customer table contains thousands or millions of rows you will be returning thousands or millions of rows to your C# code to be filtered down to just a single row. It would be far better to ask SQL to do the filtering for you and return only the single row required back to your C# code.

You can do this with a Parameterized Query, such as the following:

```cs
public static DataTable getReportById(int customerId)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(SqlUpdater.conString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT customerName as 'name' FROM customer where customerId = @Id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", customerId);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This didn't seem to work. I just keep getting the same thing. I thing it might be because of the return.dt but after commenting that out, the getReport method doesn't have anything to return...

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get some columns from the database, put them into a datatable, then filter the datatable using the Linq query, and display the results in a datagridview

Comment: Thanks! Thats a big help! I realize it's rather inefficient, but its a small test database, and using a Linq/Lambda is part of the requirements. Normally I would use parameters.